# How to run pkg-config (for GTK+-3.0) installed through MSYS under windows and get Absolute Path

Tags: c++, eclipse, gtk, msys, pkg-config

I'm facing the following problem. I installed GTK+-3.0 and pkg-config through MSYS64. `pkg-config.exe` is located in `C:\msys64\usr\bin` and I added that to the PATH of windows environment. If I run

```
pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags
```

As a result, I get a series of include paths referred to the drive mounted on msys (either running under cmd.exe or msys shell)

```
-mms-bitfields -pthread -mms-bitfields -I/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0 -I/mingw64/include/cairo [and_so_on...]
```

Now I'm trying to set Eclipse for GTK development (I would like to avoid pkg-config package which, however, presents the same issue). If I add the content of pkg-config to the **Command Line Pattern** of the Compiler and the linker options, I get (obvously) no inclusion

```
fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory
```

How can I make `pkg-config` point to the absolute path under windows? (`C:\msys64\......`)
I'm struggling with this (probably dull) problem but I can't find a solution.

Comment: `pkg-config` should give you the absolute paths. Is gtk not located under c:/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0 ?

Comment: gtk is located under C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0. It gives the relative paths however... And I don't understand why...

Answer (score 2):

gtkmm is a separate project from GTK+. The correct `#include` is

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
```

and the correct `pkg-config` argument is `gtkmm-3.0`.

You also installed the MSYS version of gtkmm and pkg-config. You need to install the MinGW-w64 version to do any meaningful development (otherwise, everything will be tied to MSYS, which is why you get the Unix paths instead of the Windows paths). This is easy: go back to your `pacman` lines and change the `msys` prefix to the appropriate `mingw` prefix for your target CPU architecture. You can see a list of the exact names using `pacman -Ss thing` (in this case, `pacman -Ss gtkmm`). Then, run that architecture's MinGW Shell instead of the MSYS Shell.

([Be sure to follow the official tutorial as well.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/))

Comment: Surely I've been superficial, however I implied that MinGW has been already (and correctly) installed (version x64, with all the essentials for C++ development). I also installed a complete bundle with GTK and GTKmm but I've been just wrong including `gtk\gtkmm.h` instead of `gtkmm.h`. The problem wasn't that. Now I'd like to try changing the prefix of msys.. How can I accomplish the goal? I didn't understand well what prefix I've to point to. Thank's a lot for the advice!

Comment: The prefix I refer to is the package name's prefix. If you are sure you installed it correctly, then you *should* just need to point your tools to the appropriate `mingw` folder in the MSYS folder... (So if you installed to `C:\msys2` and this is 64-bit, it would be `C:\msys2\mingw64`.)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not understanding... I've MSYS (64bit) installed in `C:\msys64` and MingW (64bit) installed in `C:\msys64\mingw64`. They work correctly. Now I run the `mingw64.exe` shell. If I type `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --variable=prefix` I get `/mingw64` as I expected. Now, wanting to obtain a `prefix=C:/msys64/mingw64`, I type `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 `--define-variable=prefix="C:/msys64/mingw64"`... However nothing changes.